# Is there any operator on Hilbert space commute with shift operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and $S$ be the left shift operator.
Is there any operator $T$ in $B(H)$ such that $TS=ST$ except $\mathbb{C}\textbf{1}$ or $0$?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe $S$ is an operator in $B(H)$ and does commute with itself, right?

Comment: @Matthias Klupsch   Sorry！so, thx, i will keep thinking

Comment: (assuming $S$ is bounded) it commutes with the convolution operators  $T = \sum_{k=a}^b c_k S^k$ or $T = \int_a^b c(x) S^x dx$

Comment: @usee1952009 THX！ it does help！

Comment: What do you mean by the left shift operator on a general separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space?

Comment: @Christian it is not accurate    should be l_2

Comment: see also this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647866/in-ellp-if-an-operator-commutes-with-left-shift-it-is-continuous

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that your guess is correct if you require $T$ to commute with both $S$ and $S^*$.  That is, if $TS = ST$ and $TS^* = S^*T$, then $T \in \mathbb{C}1$.  See, for example, the remark after Theorem 4.1.12 [here](https://www.math.uh.edu/~tomforde/Textbooks/Murphy%20-%20C-Star%20Algebras%20&%20Operator%20Theory.pdf).

Comment: @JoshKeneda wOO, it could be useful! Thx!

Comment: Are you talking about a shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ or on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$? It makes a difference because the first $S$ is not normal, while the second is unitary.

Comment: @TrialAndError Actually, I just wanna find a case such that my guess holds true. If $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ holds, I will take it, if not, I will take the other one.